# concat std::vector and initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, insert, initializer-list

In c++11 you can do this wonderful syntax:

```
vector<int> numbers = {1, 2, 3};
```

Is there a way to concatenate a further initializer list onto an existing vector?

```
numbers.??? ({4, 5, 6});
```

or

```
std::??? (numbers, {4, 5, 6});
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) for that:

```
#include <vector>

vector<int> numbers = {1, 2, 3};
numbers.insert( numbers.end(), {4, 5, 6} );
```

Answer (score 10):

Use [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert):

```
numbers.insert(numbers.end(), {4, 5, 6});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `std::vector::insert`. [Link to example code](http://ideone.com/dszCUu)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> a = {1,2,3};
    a.insert(a.end(), {4,5,6});
    for(int &i : a) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```